# Can I discard part of a multi-city (not layover) ticket?

Tags: air-travel, airports, airlines, layovers

My destination is B. My origin is A. I can buy a multi-city ticket from A->B->C which is cheaper than just A->B.

Note that this is a multi city trip and not just a layover at B.

My question is if I can check my baggage at A and take it off at B. I will obviously ask the agent while checking in at A to check it in to A only.

This is a one-way international ticket.

EDIT: I don't think I was clear. This is **not a layover.** Please see the itinerary I have attached as an image as let me know if your answer is still valid.[image]

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate. Please see my edit. I have provided more information which I hope makes my question clearer.

Comment: I guess Doha is your intended final destination? Since there's more than 24 hours between your flights, you will certainly be allowed to reclaim your bags in Doha. But this question has also been answered on this site before. Whether it's "multi-city" or a "layover" really makes very little difference, what matters more is how long you'll be out of the airport.  Even if you book a "single" flight with a 24-hour layover, you'll generally be permitted to claim your luggage, because the airline knows you'll be going to a hotel.

Comment: Doha is my intended destination. The time between the flights is slightly under 3 hours. In any case, I called Qatar Airways and they told me I can check my bags to just Doha (from Ottawa) and will have to re-checkin at Doha if I want to do what I described.

Comment: Oh, I read the image wrong, yes, 3 hours. Anyway, it sounds like calling them was the appropriate action, and you got your answer. Enjoy your time in Doha :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, most airlines would not allow you to check baggage to B in this circumstance.

One exception... if B->C is domestic you might HAVE to take your luggage off at B to clear customs. (For example if you're talking about LHR-JFK-LAX you *will* get your luggage at JFK even if it's "checked" to LAX)

In some circumstances, airlines might allow you to book a layover in B at the same price as A->B->C. For example if you are booking JFK-LHR-TLV British Airways almost always lets you layover in London and calculates the fare based on JFK-TLV. In this case you could check your baggage to LHR and not show up for the LHR->TLV segment.

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: I called Qatar Airways and confirmed what you suggested with them. Thanks!